# How can i check that string is null or not and while checking condition it throws a null pointer exception

Tags: java

```
 filterType = 0;

            if((Name !=  " " &&  !Name .isEmpty() ) |( userName != " " && !userName.isEmpty() ) | userLock == true | (HQ !=  " " && !HQ.isEmpty() ) |  Area !=  0.0  | Route != 0.0 | ( Label != " " && !Label.isEmpty() )){

                filterType = filterType + 1;
            }



            if( (Phone != " " && !Phone.isEmpty() ) | (URL != " " && !URL.isEmpty()) |( City != " " && !City.isEmpty() ) |  (Date != " " && !Date.isEmpty())| (Email != " " && !Email.isEmpty()) ){
                filterType = filterType + 2;

            }
```

If any of above string contains value then filter type should be added but java throws null pointer exception. How can I fix it?

Comment: `name!=null` string not `null`

Comment: userName.isEmpty() will give you a nullpointer exception if it's null, so check that it's `!= null` first

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java and then think carefully about what that will do in your case if `Name` is a null reference...

Comment: I can see that you are a new user here, so I'm gonna give you a tip: When Jon Skeet writes, read, and do what he says :). He is the highest ranked member of this community, and by that, one of the most important people of computer programming in the world.

Comment: @Kjetil: There are too many things wrong with this code to find a good duplicate. nikita: Using | for "or" is a bad idea here, use || instead (since it short-circuits). it's totally unclear to me what the logic should be, possibly a misunderstanding of boolean logic is involved? You probably should read up on DeMorgan's rule.

Answer (score 0):

When checking if a `String` is `null` in Java, you could use

`name == null`. This returns `true`, if your `String` is in fact `null`

Note that I have deliberately changed the variable name from `Name` to `name`. variable names should never start with an upper case letter, as that is conventionally used for class definitions. Pretty much every Java developer would find your code hard to read, if you do not follow this convention.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed like this:

```
if(name != null && !" ".equals(name) && !name.isEmpty()) {
    ....
}
```

- Evaluate if an object is `null` before calling a method on it
- Prefer `" ".equals(name)` instead of `name.equals(" ")` because is other situations (not this one) `name` may be `null`
- Never compare a `String` value with `==` but always use `equals()`
  [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- `|` is the *bitwise or* : maybe did you mean the *short-circuit or* `||` in your code? See the [Nathan Hughes' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655752/how-can-i-check-my-string-is-null-or-not-and-while-checking-null-or-not-conditio/31655942#comment51259113_31655752)
- Consider to name always variables in lowercase and *camel casing* letters
- Drive only if not drunk

... or consider to write a function to test common invalid values:

```
static boolean isUseless(String value) {
    return value == null || " ".equals(value) || value.isEmpty();
}
```

... or convert your strings before use:

```
static String convertToNotNull(String value) {
    return value == null ? "" : value.trim();
}
```